# How can I convert SharePoint App solution into normal .WSP solution?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development, sharepoint-addin

I have a sharepoint-hosted app and I want to convert it into an normal `.wsp` solution instead of `.app`

I was wondering if there is a change to make this conversion.

Thank you.

Comment: Create one visual webpart in visual studio and add all javascript into that webpart. Add create wsp of that solution.

Comment: How can I add javascript to my webpart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here below are the steps for that:

- Create **Empty SharePoint Solution** in Visual Studio.
- Choose **SharePoint sandbox solution** in that.
- Create one visual webpart from **add new item**.
- Find the JavaScript code from the SharePoint app code.
- Add that code in the visual webpart or attach JS file in that webpart.
- Add related HTML code in the visual webpart.
- Do rebuild and deploy the solution.

Comment: I don't know what to say to you! I LOVE YOU. You saved my life bro.